# How to connect importMappings and yaml in Swagger

Tags: spring, api, gradle, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have Spring RESTfull application and I want to generate an API for it. I use a gradle configuration from there https://github.com/Casturan/swagger-gradle-example/blob/master/build.gradle to generate code. But there is problem it uses models defined in `definitions:` while I want it to use my models from shared module. I found that I need to use importMapping but when I try to apply this command in my build.gradle I am getting an error:

```
importMappings = [
   'board_container': 'board_container=com.workingbit.share.domain.impl.BoardContainer'
]
> Could not set unknown property 'importMappings' for task ':myproject:generateApi' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

So question how to use `importMapping` and how to connect it with my model in `yaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but looking at the code of `CodegenConfigurator` modifying the `generateApi` task like this in the `build.gradle` might work:

```
task generateApi {
  inputs.file("$projectDir/$swaggerSourceFile")
  outputs.dir("$projectDir/$swaggerTargetFolder")
  doLast{
    def config = new CodegenConfigurator()
    config.setInputSpec("file:///$projectDir/$swaggerSourceFile")
    config.setOutputDir("$projectDir")
    config.setLang('spring')
    config.setAdditionalProperties([
        'interfaceOnly' : 'true',
        'apiPackage'    : 'com.dturan.api',
        'modelPackage'  : 'com.dturan.model',
        'sourceFolder'  : swaggerTargetFolder
    ])
    //Add this line
    config.addImportMapping("board_container", "com.workingbit.share.domain.impl.BoardContainer")
    new DefaultGenerator().opts(config.toClientOptInput()).generate()
  }
}
```

The `CodegenConfigurator` is being called at the second line in the `build.gradle` you linked to in your question and it has a few methods to configure `importMappings`. You can have a look [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/8314f4e78a481554eb3cf1acfdcaa634b6661916/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/config/CodegenConfigurator.java#L290) (if this doesn't work try with the `setImportMappings`).